# jss build command does nothing

Tags: jss

I'm currently setting up the JSS CLI on my build server so that I can run continuous integration builds. I installed the CLI with the command:

`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`

And it appeared to successfully install version 13.0.5.

As a quick test I went to my working directory that had the source files and ran `jss build`, but the command didn't seem to do anything and the only output was:

`JSS CLI is running in global mode because it was not installed in the local node_modules folder.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run `npm install` prior to `jss build`.

Comment: Also make sure that @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli is included in the package.json, otherwise the npm install will have no effect